# Example python implementation of generator/yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, python-internals

Let's take the following python code to generate an infinite counter:

```
def infinite_sequence():
    num = 0
    while True:
        yield num
        num += 1
```

I can then call this as:

```
for i in infinite_sequence():
    print (i)
```

And do a `KeyboardInterrupt` whenever I want to exit it. The `yield/generator` stuff is implemented in C/Cpython. What would be an example of implementing a similar "generator functionality" within python? That is, if I could call a function/method in place of the `yield num` line, and get the same functionality, what would be an example implementation of this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to implement the iterator protocol yourself.

```
class InfiniteSequence:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        x = self.x
        self.x = x + 1
        return x


for i in InfiniteSequence():
    print(i)
```

The `__iter__` method has to return something that implements `__next__`. The `__next__` method has to return the next value in the sequence. The instance attribute maintains state between calls to `__next__`.

The same class doesn't have to implement both methods. You might want a separate iterator class so that you can have multiple, independent iterators over the iterable sequence.

```
class InfiniteSequence:
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def __iter__(self):
        return InfSeqIterator(self.start)


class InfSeqIterator:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        x = self.x
        self.x += 1
        return x


nats = InfiniteSequence()

i1 = iter(nats)
i2 = iter(nats)

assert next(i1) == 0
assert next(i2) == 0  # not 1
```

---

`generator` is just one example of a class that implements this protocol; you create an instance of `generator` using either a generator expression (`(x for x in [1,2,3])`) or a generator function (i.e., a function that uses `yield`).

Comment: how does the python/cpython infer the `__next__` method (or its equivalent) from the context of the `yield` statement?

Comment: That's really a question for examining the source code of whatever implementation you are interested in; it's not something the Python language defines.

Comment: Why is a detour needed in incrementing `self.x`?

Comment: Because you want to return the current value of `self.x`, not the incremented value. You could avoid that by initializing `self.x` to one less than the start value; then you can increment it and return it. I just didn't.

Comment: @chepner could you please link to the python part of the Iterator protocol? Here's the C version: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/iter.html. As a side-note, I wish that python's docs were better represented in search (both on Google and the python search itself is pretty poor).